# eCATT Error when Starting Replay Session CX_ECATT_APL_CAPTURE CX_APL_ECATT_LINE_INTERPRETER SAPGUI RFC

Tags: automation, sap-gui, saprfc

When I want to replay my script in à RFC target I have this error :

> ```
> Error in eCATT command SAPGUI
> Error when Starting Replay Session
> ExceptionClass:CX_ECATT_APL_CAPTURE
> RaisingClass:CL_APL_ECATT_LINE_INTERPRETER
> ```
>
> [image]

Can you help me ?

Best regards.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming issue, but rather a system configuration issue.

Comment: Can you give me more detail for the system configuration.